# Can't run "Open Browser" with a Firefox (version 20) instance through Robot Framework IDE + Selenium

Tags: windows, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I'm looking for a way to, making use of RIDE and the Robot Framework, run Firefox (version 20 -- the latest), opening a page of my liking. This used to pose no concern with earlier Firefox versions, but there now seems to be problems relating to Firefox 20's way of dealing with profiles. When I try to run the usual Open Browser command, Firefox pops up but with no URL in the title and lifeless.

Selenium Firefox's driver seems to provide a way to define which profile directory to look for, but that seems to be of no avail:

[image]

(the given directory corresponds to a new profile I've created via Firefox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution: 
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5508
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

From [enter link description here](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5508#c4), I found this : "When there's a custom profile, the resulting profile path "newprof" may be a unicode string and webdriver accepts only bytestrings."

Try adding and removing some lines in selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py, details are here : [https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/55/files#r4178907](http://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/pull/55/files#r4178907)

Answer (score 0):

Selenium is saying you need to upgrade to 2.32.0 to make it compatible with FF 20. However when I do this I get a different problem: it throws a "TypeError: environment can only contain strings"

I am still looking for a solution to the problem myself...maybe you can upgrade Selenium and see if you have the same result?

Answer (score 0):

I also encounter `TypeError: environment can only contain strings` when I try robotframework with firefox.

Reason: 
    Because in selenium-2.32.0-py2.7.egg package, file `selenium\webdriver\firefox\firefox_profile.py` will use `from __future__ import unicode_literals`, so firefox profile.path will be unicode dict. 
so when `_start_from_profile_path()` invoke `Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, env=self._firefox_env).communicate()`, pops up the TypeError.

Solution:
    Update Selenium lib to latest version or delete `from __future__ import unicode_literals` line in `firefox_profile.py`

Answer (score 0):

Go to firefox_profile.py file and remove the first line and add the second line instead. (line number 157)

py/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_profile.py

- return self.profile_dir
- return str(self.profile_dir)

This worked perfectly fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Please check that you have add the geckodriver.exe file to your Python installation folder. The default location is in C drive. e.g- C:\Python27.

Answer (score -2):

It is always good to use latest and stable version of browser. Please ensure you have latest geckodriver.exe  and install Firefox ESR version.